# Arrays contain value call by Reference so their pointer should turn same values and equate to true

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

As far as I know, the `arrays` and `objects` always act as `pointers` and just point to **somewhere a memory location**.

In the following example, as `var a` is updated, so as `b` pointing to same memory location as a, should also be updated and final answer should be **true, true**.

Why is it not happening??? **At what instance of time**, *b gets a different pointer than a and why*???

**Example:**

```js
var a = [2,3,5];
var b = a; 
a = [33,45];
console.log(a,b);
console.log(a==b,a===b);
```

However, to support my clause kindly look at following unchanged values example. Here I am sure both a and b point to same memory location containing data as [2,3,5]. They got same values and are always equated as true.

```js
var a = [2,3,5];
var b = a; 
console.log(a==b,a===b);
```

Comment: I hope this is a proper question, that I don't understand. Kindly explain before downvoting!

Comment: I don't mind downvoting, but will you please, explain the jeopardy in answer please?

Comment: When you change the value of `a`, `b` will keep the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not updating the reference of the new object [33, 45].

Following code might help you understand better.

```js
a = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}];
b = a;
console.log(a, b);

// creates new object and assigns to the same variable
b = b.concat ([{'c': 3}]);
console.log(a, b);

// but property of object is still referenced in by a and b
b[0].a = 100;
console.log(a,b);

a[2].c = 100; // throws exception, because 'a' does not have the reference to object which refers the object created in 'b'
console.log(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

look at blow:

```
var a = [2,3,5];
var b = a;
```

[image]

and after the `a = [33,45];`
[image]

the pointer is point to a new obj, not the obj changed